# Does Reinforcement Learning Make Sense for my task?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I've been tasked with using RL to detect a specific and sudden change in real-time waveforms.  But I can't think of a way to frame it as a purely RL problem!  The issue is that the algorithm won't be able to learn on its own; its reward would be based on how close it was to the time at which the change occurred.  So if I simulated the waveforms, I would have to label each input waveform with the correct time. If I did the test in real life, I'd have to manually set the reward myself depending on how close it was. I don't think there's a way to do this without some form of supervision.

The other issue is I'm not sure what the states/actions would be.  I guess the action is detecting whether or not the change has occurred, but there wouldn't be a transition to a new state (kind of like the multi-armed bandit problem).  Does anyone have any advice?  Thank you!

Comment: I think I do not have enough information to be definitive, but it seems more suited for an online learning approach.

Comment: Definitely sounds neat but I struggle to see how any possible implementation of this would outperform standard classification or some basic logic for the 'sudden change'.

Comment: Are you sure it was supposed to be reinforcement learning? RL is about taking decision, whereas here you seem to need to perform sequence classification